# The task is: Given a group of integers, find the maximum value among them all, how do i do it without arrays using c++?

Tags: c++

The task is: Given a group of integers, find the maximum value among them all.

Input
Givin an integer N (1≤N≤10^5) – the number of integers to be entered.

The following line contains N space-separated integers (−10^18≤ai≤10^18) — ai is the value of the ith integer.

Output
Print the answer to the task.

```
Examples
input
4
3 5 1 4
output
5
```

and this is my code which gives me wrong on answer test 3#

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
void main()
{
long long b,c=0;
int a;
cin>>a;
for (int i = 0; i<a ; i++)
{
cin>>b;
if (b>=c)
c=b;
else
c=c;
}
cout<<c;
}
```

Comment: `c=0` So, what if the largest number is negative? Use the first value read as a starting value instead.

Comment: Which tests did you try on your code? If those used by the judge are unknown, which tests did you invent yourself to try on your code? How did you use the given ranges to come up with test cases?

Comment: What is the purpose of `c=c;`?

Answer (score 2):

The inputted integers can be negative. When all the integers are negative, your code will print out 0 since that is bigger than all the input integers. A possible way to fix this is to set c to -10^18. Another way would be to somehow initialize c as the first value.